# Encrypt CSS external link and restrict access to it

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, encryption, hyperlink

I have a new client who asked me to make 2 websites and no payment so far! 
I have the ftp accounts, but he can always close my access and leave me without pay. 
Can I upload the CSS to another server of mine and encrypt the link to CSS file? 
If yes, can I restrict peoples to see the file if they find the URL to CSS file?

Thank you!

Comment: No. Instead, send a screenshot.

Comment: Wait, his sites are already live and he hasn't paid you? Did I read that right?

Comment: :) Yeah, I usually ask for 50% of money after screen preview and the rest after, but this client is from my town and I can hunt him down :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a simple PHP file that allows you to access, edit and delete files on the server. You can also search for a ready made lightweight ftp script. Place the PHP file somewhere on the server nested in other folders and name it something like temp.php. Now even if the client blocked you access to the server, you can still access, edit and delete files on the server by pointing your URL to temp.php. When you get paid, be kind enough to remove the file. Don't forget to password protect it.

In your PHP file you can use [opendir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) to read files from a directory, and [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete files. If all you want to do is be able to delete files, then the script will not take you more then a minute to create.

**UPDATE**
You can use the following lightweight ftp script that will let you view, edit delete files and also give you the option to password protect it. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pafm/

Comment: Can you give me an link to a script like that? Thank you!

Comment: I will look into these php functions! Hope not to late :P! Thank you very much!

Comment: @florescu see updated post for a link to a lightweight FTP script. If all you want to do is delete files then don't really need the ftp script. Just create your own php file and use `opendir()` and `unlink()` to do it. It will only be 1 file that can be easily hidden anywhere

Comment: @florescu: You should be **very** careful if you choose to do this. When you access `temp.php`, your hits will probably be logged in the `access.log` file or similar on the server. After files vanish, if the client asked *someone else* to "see who hacked the server", they could look inside `access.log`, and find that someone purposely removed the files. Worse, they could geolocate your IP stored in the log, and find that you're from the same town as the client. Which makes it quite obvious you did it. Proceed with caution!

Comment: That's not the point. it will be obvious that files were deleted because of non payment. No need for access logs to tell the story.

Comment: @Hussein: IANAL, but I'm not sure how legal it is to delete files from someone else's website without their consent. It's irrelevant that payment has not been received for the creation of the website in question.

Comment: @thirtydot You're still missing the point. No pay, No files. Concept is simple. It's also not legal for customer to use your files without pay.

Comment: @Hussein: No, I think you're missing the point. It probably is illegal to delete files off somebody else's server. It's only illegal not to pay somebody for work done if you had a proper contract drawn up (doesn't sound like the OP has one). In any case, two wrongs don't make a right, and I'd wager that the offence which sounds suspiciously close to hacking is *more illegal*. See @Jim's answer, he's saying a similar thing to me.

Comment: @thirtydot Still not getting it. You seem too concerned. I suggest you don't use this method if it scares you.

Comment: @Hussein: It doesn't "scare" me - it's just **illegal**. Honestly, would you ever use this method yourself? If you say no: Then why are you recommending it? If you say yes: .. I have nothing more to say.

Comment: @thirtydot I definitely use it when needed and if i smell a flaky customer.

Comment: @Hussein: I guess we're talking about.. shall we say.. *different* sorts of clients. I guess you could get away with this with *that* type of client. I don't think your idea was bad enough to downvote, but I do think you should have added that it might be illegal (though I seem to have done a good job of that for you now :) ). I have no further interest in this discussion.

Comment: @thirtydot Another way you can do this and if a certain client concerns you, is print it somewhere in your contract and have the customer sign it before working on his project.

Answer (score 3):

If they are his hosting accounts, then accessing them to tamper with the code for the purpose of disabling his sites without his authorisation is probably illegal.

If he hasn't paid you, you own the copyright.  If he refuses to pay you, file a DMCA complaint with his hosting company.

Technological measures like this are futile and unprofessional.  Next time use a contract.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple. Same scenario happened to me, and what I did was added an new index.html which was an under-construction page, and renamed the original index.php as index_to_be.php.

I then added a redirection using htaccess to the new index.html.
The client contacted me straight away and paid up in no time.

If you don't know how to use htaccess, you can simply add a header location value to the top php page.

```
header("location:index.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the style sheet from the client's site, upload it to one of your servers and embed it from there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://your.server/styles.css">
```

however, you will not be able to seriously obfuscate this. One idea that comes to mind is to add a huge number of spaces before the "link" tag to hide it in the source code view.

```
                                                                                                               <link rel="stylesheet".....>
```

You could also lazy load it using jQuery, but that would disable the style sheet for users who have JavaScript turned off - mostly a no-go.

In the end, no matter what you do, all this will be trivially easy to circumvent. There is no way to reliably keep control over the site in the scenario you describe. Like @thirtydot says, the best thing to do is to send a screenshot instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably like trying to kill a fly with a ICBM but...

You could always use a JavaScript to add the link element to the DOM, and run the JavaScript code through a JS obfusticator.

But still, that's hackish, and overkill, and ways you can get the link anyway.