# How to encode .css file?

Tags: css, encoding

I have created a website. And I want to give the file to my client. The client can also see and change the styling. I want to encode that file so no one can replace it. Can You give me a better solution so that only I can change the styling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt CSS external link and restrict access to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207501/encrypt-css-external-link-and-restrict-access-to-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS is a plain text format that needs to be read by a browser as CSS. There's nothing you can do to restrict access to it and still have it usable. If a browser can download and use the file, so can anybody else. You could obfuscate the contents a bit by stripping all unneeded whitespace and things like that, but this is easily reversed with a CSS pretty-printer. Even actually encrypting the file and post-processing it with Javascript doesn't help, since the end result of whatever your decryption script does still needs to be plain CSS.

So: no, not really. You may be able to deter really dumb clients by obfuscation, but you cannot actually keep it secret.

Comment: is there any simple way i can remove the white space

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can encode a CSS file and have it still be read by a browser -- but I might be wrong. You should host the CSS file on a separate server, that will be easier. For example. if your clients site is example.com and your site is awesome.com, then host the CSS file on awesome.com that way only you can make edits.

Comment: but he is asking for css file also

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to base64 encode your .css script

```
<html><head>
<title>Hello World!</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css;base64,Ym9keSB7IHdpZHRoOiA5NjBweDsgbWFyZ2luOiBhdXRvO30gcCB7IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiBWZXJkYW5hO30" type="text/css">

</head><body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body></html>
```

Use a site like http://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: i think this can implement after uploading the page.But client want to edit in html file so i given the html file.but he is asking for css file also.Its not yet uploaded.Before uploading he want to edit something

Comment: It was a nice idea, but simply pasting the `data:text/css;base64,Ym9keSB7IHdpZHRoOiA5NjBweDsgbWFyZ2luOiBhdXRvO30gcCB7IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiBWZXJkYW5hO30` in the address bar reveals the styles.
 `body { width: 960px; margin: auto;} p { font-family: Verdana;}`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to protect against. I once put "poison" code  into a CSS style to protect against stealing the webpage. The style was accompanied by a heavily obfuscated JS script which did an origin check before "neutralising" the poison. Then I wrote a server-side script to cram all of the CSS on the webpage into a single file, then inflate it to about three times the size by injecting dead code in between the useful CSS rules, put the poison in random places inside this file and then fully minify it. It's pretty hard for a regular user to find and remove six lines of code crammed in a 3-megabyte CSS full of random junk that looks just like normal code, but an experienced web dev or a security expert could do that in a matter of minutes.